# How to generate a random number from the range 1-500 excluding numbers from the file?

Tags: ansible

Im try this one but always have problem with var my_list - i cant use path to file.

```
  vars:
    my_list: "{{ lookup('file', 'id.txt') }}"
  tasks:
- name: run shell to get random number
  shell: exit `shuf -i 1-500 -n 1` 
  register: shell_command
  failed_when: shell_command.rc > 500
  until: shell_command.rc not in my_list
  retries: 1000
  delay: 1
  delegate_to: localhost


- name: print results
  debug:
    var: shell_command.rc
```

how to do this in ansible?
the contents of the id.txt file are below

```
349
104
182
111
180
196
```

Comment: Do you need a pseudo random uniform distribution?

Comment: @TheImpaler I need a number from 1 to 500 but it shouldn't be in the file id.txt

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _range|difference(my_list)|random }}"
      vars:
        my_list: "{{ lookup('file', 'id.txt').splitlines()|map('int')|list }}"
        _range: "{{ range(1, 501) }}"
```

Comment: That's an very good example for usage of [Selecting from sets or lists (set theory)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory).